# forbidden to play with kosher animals?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, animals

Looking for source that forbidden to play with kosher animals

Lubavicher Rebbe says that it is forbidden to play with kosher animals ([lekutai sichos 1 shmini 1](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15859&st=&pgnum=237) (the Hebrew version does not translate it)) what is his source

PS it is possible it is only animals that (need shechita) not fish or insects
https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.90b.5

Comment: Forbidden is a strong word. That’s not what the Lubavitcher rebbe said

Answer (score 1):

The footnote to the Sicha says the [Yerushalmi Shabbos](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Shabbat.9.7.7?ven=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_translation_and_commentary_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&vhe=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_edition_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&lang=he&with=Penei%20Moshe&lang2=he) end of perek 9.

Comment: Thank I did not know this foot note was regarding this

Comment: Can you help explain the rest of the foot note, (also or did not way yerushalmi clearly